# How does MongoVUE "copy collection to different server" feature work?

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

I need to know how the MongoVUE "copy collection to different server" feature (right-click on a collection node and the option is available in the context menu) works. I want to compare it from a performance point of view to the `mongodump`/`mongorestore` option.

Does anybody know what shell commands MongoVUE issues behind the scenes? How does it stream data and which is the memory/disk space consumption during the process?

I was thinking about [db.cloneCollection()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/), but in the docs they say

> [It] does not allow you to clone a collection through a mongos. You must
>   connect directly to the mongod instance.

which does not happen. My MongoVUE connections are tied to `mongos` ports.